# How do I launch a window from an already running WPF system-tray application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that runs in the system-tray & monitors HTTP activity.

When I right-click my system tray icon, I can launch a "Control Panel" from a context menu command.

However, when a user goes to `StartMenu\Programs\MYAPPLICATION` and clicks on menu item called "Control Panel" I would like to fire a method that displays the control panel (just a regular WPF Window),

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On application launch you could check if there is another instance running. Then via interprocess communication of your choice (e.g. WCF, named pipes, .NET remoting, a drop file, etc) you could instruct the original instance (via whatever means the chosen communication method provides) to show the required window.

Comment: I eventually Sorted this issue using Named Pipes. Thanks for pointing me in that direction